# Failed to create nx workspace

Tags: node.js, npx

I am new in NX, and even new in NodeJS ecosystem. As I found interesting tool to scaffold full-stack application development, where is NX, then I gave a try. But I always failed in the first step in creating nx-workspace. Right not, I am using Node version 14.16 LTS, and npm version 6.14.11 on Windows Pro 64-bit. Here is the errors:

```
    C:\Projects>npx create-nx-workspace --preset=angular
? Workspace name (e.g., org name)     hw
? Application name                    shop
? Default stylesheet format           CSS
? Default linter                      ESLint [ Modern linting tool ]
? Use Nx Cloud? (It's free and doesn't require registration.) No

>  NX  Nx is creating your workspace.

  To make sure the command works reliably in all environments, and that the preset is applied correctly,
  Nx will run "npm install" several times. Please wait.

added 229 packages from 170 contributors and audited 230 packages in 9.112s

32 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

- Creating your workspace
>  NX   ERROR  Something went wrong. Rerunning the command with verbose logging.

Failed to format: hw\angular.json
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined
    at Function.from (buffer.js:333:9)
    at FsTree.write (C:\Users\PTGENTS\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-11296frnzjs2oVb4Z\node_modules\@nrwl\tao\src\shared\tree.js:35:20)
    at writeJson (C:\Users\PTGENTS\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-11296frnzjs2oVb4Z\node_modules\@nrwl\devkit\src\utils\json.js:32:10)
    at Object.updateJson (C:\Users\PTGENTS\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-11296frnzjs2oVb4Z\node_modules\@nrwl\devkit\src\utils\json.js:44:5)
    at formatWorkspaceJson (C:\Users\PTGENTS\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-11296frnzjs2oVb4Z\node_modules\@nrwl\workspace\src\generators\workspace\workspace.js:53:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\PTGENTS\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-11296frnzjs2oVb4Z\node_modules\@nrwl\workspace\src\generators\workspace\workspace.js:78:9)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\PTGENTS\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-11296frnzjs2oVb4Z\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:114:62) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
UPDATE hw/nx.json
UPDATE hw/package.json
UPDATE hw/.vscode/extensions.json
UPDATE hw/angular.json

> hw@0.0.0 postinstall C:\Projects\hw
> node ./decorate-angular-cli.js


>  NX  Angular CLI has been decorated to enable computation caching.

npm WARN @cypress/webpack-preprocessor@4.1.5 requires a peer of webpack@^4.18.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @nrwl/cypress@11.6.1 requires a peer of cypress@>= 3 < 7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN babel-loader@8.2.2 requires a peer of webpack@>=2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

removed 1506 packages and audited 799 packages in 21.916s

56 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

MergeConflictException [Error]: A merge conflicted on path "/apps/shop/tsconfig.editor.json".
    at C:\Projects\hw\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\src\tree\host-tree.js:142:35
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HostTree.merge (C:\Projects\hw\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\src\tree\host-tree.js:131:23)
    at MapSubscriber.project (C:\Projects\hw\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\src\rules\base.js:54:91)
    at MapSubscriber._next (C:\Projects\hw\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:49:35)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Projects\hw\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)
    at TapSubscriber._next (C:\Projects\hw\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:65:26)
    at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Projects\hw\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)
    at ThrowIfEmptySubscriber._next (C:\Projects\hw\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\throwIfEmpty.js:44:26)
    at ThrowIfEmptySubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Projects\hw\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)
A merge conflicted on path "/apps/shop/tsconfig.editor.json".
Workspace creation failed, see above.
(node:11296) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Command failed: npx tao new hw --preset=angular --no-interactive --appName=shop --style=css --linter=eslint --no-nxCloud --collection=@nrwl/workspace/collection.json --cli=angular --nxWorkspaceRoot="C:/Projects"
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:652:15)
    at C:\Users\PTGENTS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-nx-workspace\bin\create-nx-workspace.js:424:29
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (C:\Users\PTGENTS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-nx-workspace\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:113:69)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:11296) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11296) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Anyone can help or give me a clue?

Comment: Encountering same issue. Were you able to resolved it?

Comment: @lego Not yet. Unfortunately.

Comment: having same issues .. any1 find a fix yet ?

Comment: I can only say I had the same issue, but I had picked `scss` - changing it to `css` worked for me. (I see you picked `css` so it's not helpful, but maybe the next person can be helped.

Comment: I've got this ```error :Nx failed to create a workspace``` first time.
and i remove the project folder using vpn and run command again but this time everything went well.

Answer (score 5):

I am facing the same issue for resolving use below command for creating new workspace:-

```
npx create-nx-workspace --preset=angular --skip-git=true
```

Comment: do we have to recreate nx workspace under same project? mostly i found this issue when your node version is old

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced same issue while doing it first time. But later it worked.
Please follow below things.

- Make sure you have node latest version
- Install angular cli [ `npm install -g @angular/cli` ]
- Install nrwl schematic [ `npm install -g @nrwl/schematics` ]

I followed these steps and it's working fine now.

You can refer this [link](https://duncanhunter.gitbook.io/enterprise-angular-applications-with-ngrx-and-nx/introduction/0-environment-setup) to do initial setup.

Comment: yea mostly it happen when you have old node version

Answer (score -2):

I was able to fix it with

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

After setting the email `npx create-nx-workspace` worked.

Answer (score -8):

make sure you have working internet connection. in my case the proxy settings were broken

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is no issue with my internet connection.